# Добавление функции вычисления факториала в калькулятор

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText txt1, txt2;
    Button add, sub, mult, div, fac;
    TextView tvTxt;

    String oper = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
        txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNum2);

        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        mult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMult);
        div = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
        fac = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFac);

        tvTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);
        mult.setOnClickListener(this);
        div.setOnClickListener(this);
        fac.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float num1 = 0;
        float num2 = 0;
        float result = 0;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt1.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt2.getText().toString())){
            return;
        }

        num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(txt2.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                oper = "+";
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case R.id.btnDiv:
                oper = "/";
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case R.id.btnMult:
                oper = "*";
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case R.id.btnSub:
                oper = "-";
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case R.id.btnFac:

        }
        tvTxt.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + result);



    }
}
```

Пишу простой калькулятор. Все простые вычисления делаются в switch. Как будет лучше добавить метод вычисления факториала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете создать отдельно метод для подсчета факториала (для удобства можно вообще в отдельный клас вынести). Для примера нерекурсивная функция может выглядеть так:

```
public static int calculateFactorial(int num) {
    int fact = 1;
    for (; num > 0; fact *= num--);
        return fact;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто я не пойму как именно это сделать